# How to keep format of date returned from Firebase Functions the same as is returned to client through the SDK

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Firebase Functions as my server for my app and my functions retrieve some data from my Firestore database and return it to the user. The date variables of objects from the database are always formatted as a string with the format:

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZ"
```

However, when I retrieve the same objects using the SDK, the dates are now returned as a Firebase `Timestamp` e.g:

```
FIRTimestamp: seconds=1520380800 nanoseconds=0>
```

How can I make the `node.js` Function code return the dates as a Firebase `Timestamp` as well?

Comment: Please show your code and database structure that doesn't behave the way you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a Firestore formatted timestamp in Node.js with the following command:

```
let myTime = new Date().toISOString()
```

Answer (score 0):

The timestamp returned is a [UNIX timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

How to convert this to a "normal" datetime is explained [here...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/847196/9267296)